# how to do alert condition for line a above/below line b

Tags: pine-script

I've found some very useful indicators, but only with basic alert.

so I wanted to update the scrips to make alerts ONLY when all condition met

I understand some alertcondition(), but not sure how I write conditions like "if 20 ema above 50ema" or

"if 50 ema below 100ema"

into alerts

here is my current code

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Ethan_M

//@version=4

study(title="Fractal + EMA", overlay=true)


ema20 = ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ema(close, 50)
ema100 = ema(close, 100)
ema200 = ema(close, 200)

plot(ema20, color=color.purple, style=plot.style_line, title="EMA20", linewidth=1)
plot(ema50, color=color.white, style=plot.style_line, title="EMA50", linewidth=1)
plot(ema100, color=color.yellow, style=plot.style_line, title="EMA100", linewidth=1)
plot(ema200, color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, title="EMA200", linewidth=1)

n = input(title="Periods", defval=2, minval=2, type=input.integer)
dnFractal = (high[n-2] < high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n+1] < high[n]) and (high[n+2] < high[n])
upFractal = (low[n-2] > low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n+1] > low[n]) and (low[n+2] > low[n])
plotshape(dnFractal, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, offset=-2, color=color.green, transp=0) // Down Arrow above candles
plotshape(upFractal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-2, color=color.red, transp=0)  // Up Arrow below candles


// Create alert condition
alertcondition(condition=upFractal and close > ema(close, 50),
     title="N03",
     message="long , bet 60%/2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example:

I want to create an alert for when ema20 is greater than ema50, and ema100 greater than 200.

In my case the alert would look like this:

```
alertcondition (ema20> ema50 and ema100> ema200, title = "Alert", message = "Buy")
```

you can also create a variable with all conditions and then put it in the alert

```
allconditions = ema20> ema50 and ema100> ema200
```

That variable will be true when all those conditions are met

```
alertcondition (allconditions, title = "Alert", message = "Buy")
```

I hope you find it useful

Comment: your answer is clear and on point， thank you!!